# How to integrate solr or elasticsearch with JPA?

Tags: jpa, solr, elasticsearch

How do elasticsearch or solr integrate with JPA so the index is kept up to date with the data?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://deepintojee.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/add-search-features-to-your-application-try-elasticsearch-part-3-attaching-indexation-to-events/) article, it might be useful, at least as a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

One option is using Hibernate & Hibernate search while connecting Hibernate search to Solr.
You can get a brief overview here: [Combining the power of Hibernate Search and Solr](http://anotherjavaday.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/combining-power-of-hibernate-search-and.html)
It will require some work, but not too much (1-2 days of work should be enough).
Let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of options you can do to keep Solr and data source in sync:
[How to keep Lucene index synchronized with Mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084186/how-to-keep-lucene-index-synchronized-with-mysql-database)

Spring (Roo):
http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/base-solr.html